# Scrape website for one data

Tags: java, web-scraping

I would like to extract the value of `<div class="score">4.1</div>` from a website with JAVA (Android). I tried `Jsoup` and even though it couldn't be simpler to use, it gives me the value in 8 seconds, which is very slow. You need to know, the page source of the site has 300,000 characters and this `<div>` is somewhere in the middle.

Even using `HttpClient` and getting the source into a `StringBuilder` then going through the whole string until the *score* part is found is faster (3-4 seconds).

I couldn't try out HtmlUnit as it requires a massive amount of jar files and after a while Eclipse always pissed itself in its confusion.

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

You may simply send a XMLhttpRequest and then search the response using search() function. I think this would be much faster.

Similar Question: [Retrieving source code using XMLhttpRequest in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728756/retrieving-source-code-using-xmlhttprequest-in-javascript)

To make the search more fast, you can simply use indexOf([sting to search],[starting index]) and specify the starting index (it doesn't needs to be very accurate, you just have to decrease your search area).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. The problem was that I read the webpage line by line then glued them together into a `StringBuilder` and searched for the specific part. Then I asked myself: why do I read the page line by line then glue them together? So instead I read the page into a `ByteArray` and converted it into a String. The scraping time became less than a second!

```
try
    {
       InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
       outputDoc = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
       int len;
       while((len=is.read(buf))>0)
       {
          outputDoc.write(buf,0, len);
       }
       outputDoc.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }

try {
    page = new String(outputDoc.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
        //here I used str.indexOf to find the part

}
```